# Old GarageBand had a legit drum roll; can't find it in 10.0

Tags: garageband

I've written quite a few tunes with older versions of GarageBand, and I always use the MIDI editor / piano roll (or whatever that note-by-note editor is called) for creating drum tracks. In the older versions of GarageBand, there was a legitimate, real, snare drum roll. It was a plain old regular note in the MIDI editor, just like a regular snare hit or bass kick. But I can't find any such thing in GarageBand 10.0. When I google for how to make a drum roll, all I see is people cramming together regular snare hits, which sounds ugly and electronic to me. For an example of what I'm talking about, listen to my tune [here](http://www.icompositions.com/music/song.php?sid=204183), at about 2:40 and 2:45. I used rolls like these throughout the tune, but these two are longer and more noticeable.

Does anyone know how to do this in GB 10.0?

Comment: Does it have to be a MIDI note roll? Or can you use an audio clip sample?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to “Orchestral > Percussion > Orchestral Kit” and go to C0 and hit H you’ll get a good drum roll. I found it by going down and holding down each key until I found it.

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what you are talking about.  It took me some time to find, but it is in there.  Snare drum roll is in "Orchestra Kit".  The note is A0.  Took me time to find because my piano controller only went down to C1.

Comment: Drat, I got my hopes up. I'm running GB 10.0.2. It has Orchestral->Percussion->Orchestral Kit. In that kit, A0 is a rolling cymbal, unfortunately not a snare drum roll. Not sure why yours would be different--I have a clean install, so maybe there was a kit that I didn't carry forward? Maybe you have an older kit that carried forward? Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: Can't you just move the note and all its associated MIDI data to the snare note? That's D1 in GM standard MIDI drum map. You should just be able to drag it to the note in the piano roll editor.